# Have my script only affect certain images not the whole page?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm fairly new to JavaScript development having not long graduated university, I'm having some issues with some JavaScript in my webpage. Currently the code allows all the images on the page to expand into a bigger view of said image. I'd just like to have this only work within my gallery on this page. Is this possible? If so how?

Obviously the problem is within the `$("img").click(function(){` but changing this to suit a certain class within the page doesn't work.

```
$("img").click(function () {
  const imgClone = $(this).parent();
  $(".gallery-bg").addClass("gallery-bg-block")
  $(".gallery-bg").append(imgClone.clone());
  $(".gallery-bg .img-item img").addClass("animated fadeIn");
  $(".gallery-bg").removeClass("animated fadeOut");
});

$(".gallery-bg").click(function () {
  $(this).addClass("animated fadeOut");
  $(this).children().children().addClass("fadeLeft");
  $(this).children().remove();

  var rmBg = $(this);

  setTimeout(() => {
    rmBg.removeClass("gallery-bg-block");
  }, 400);
});
```

I want this code to be used with certain images within the webpage.

Comment: `but changing this to suit a certain class within the page doesn't work` why?

Comment: "Obviously the problem is within the $("img").click(function(){ but changing this to suit a certain class within the page doesn't work." Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Not sure.. hence the question??

Comment: Add a class to your images, like `.cusImage`, and target that instead of `img`. The comments are asking you why that approach wouldn't work, as your statement suggests.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be adding a specific class to the images you want to be affected by the script.

```
<img src="/path/of/image" class="enableMyScript">

$(".enableMyScript").click(function () {
  const imgClone = $(this).parent();
  $(".gallery-bg").addClass("gallery-bg-block")
  $(".gallery-bg").append(imgClone.clone());
  $(".gallery-bg .img-item img").addClass("animated fadeIn");
  $(".gallery-bg").removeClass("animated fadeOut");
});
```

Comment: Yes this was my first though but I'm not getting the result I'm after. I must be making an error somewhere then.

Comment: <div class="col-md-3 align-self-center">
              <div class="img-wrapper">
                <div class="img-item text-center">
                  <img src="https://www.purition.co.uk/media/gallery-1.jpg" alt="" class="enableMyScript">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

Comment: where is DOM with gallery-bg class name?

Comment: $(".img").click(function () {
  const imgClone = $(this).parent();
  $(".gallary-bg").addClass("gallary-bg-block");
  $(".gallary-bg").append(imgClone.clone());
  $(".gallary-bg .img-item img").addClass("animated fadeIn");
  $(".gallary-bg").removeClass("animated fadeOut");
});

Comment: <div class="col-md-3 align-self-center">
              <div class="img-wrapper">
                <div class="img-item text-center">
                  <img src="https://www.purition.co.uk/media/gallery-1.jpg" alt="" class="img">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>